# Reducing the size of a working copy by removing .svn/text-base files?

Tags: svn, version-control

I would like to reduce the size of my local working copy by removing the text-base files used by SVN. Is there an svn command for that? Can I disable creation of these files? Would it cause a problem if I remove them manually?

Comment: If it is needed, I am using SVN version 1.6.17 on linux.

Comment: What's your WC size? What kind of files do you have there?

Comment: I have mostly text files and pdfs in my repository. However I don't see the relevance of that to my question.

Answer (score 3):

In Subversion, the `.svn` directories are used to keep track of your Subversion working copy state. In Subversion before version 1.7, each directory had a copy of the `.svn` directory. In the `.svn` directory are stored several items that your Subversion client uses:

- The `base` files. These are copies of what you've checked out. This allows Subversion to do diffs and to verify if a file has been modified without having to pester the server. This was a design decision made when Subversion was architected. Hard disk space is cheap and network traffic can be slow.
- The properties on files in the working directory and the property values.
- Who owns the local working directory
- The information about where the checkout and revision of the working directory.

The general policy is don't touch the `.svn` directories unless you want to forever corrupt your copy of your local working directory. No user serviceable parts inside.

If you simply want the contents of the Subversion repository revision for that URL and aren't going to do any sort of version control operation, you can do a `svn export` instead of a `svn checkout`. This will give you the same directory layout as a `svn checkout` sans the `.svn` directories.

Of course, if you do a `svn export`, your directory will have no connection to the Subversion repository. You can't update the directory, make changes and commit those changes back to Subversion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but nevertheless I answer.

I think that a SVN checkout keeps all the history since its checkout. If you want to clear this, consider committing all changes, delete the local checkout folder and checkout the folder again.

Cleanup does not clean in .svn directory.